# How to add buffer to a polygon crossing the dateline in PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to add 10km-buffer to a polygon of Russian administrative boundary with PostGIS functions just like below.

```
SELECT ST_Multi(ST_Buffer(geom::geography, 10000)::geometry)
FROM example.russian_boundary;
```

However the results looks like this and it is not what I'm expecting:

[image]

The buffered-polygon should be like this, which is almost the same look as the original one:

[image]

I think this fails because the polygon is crossing the dateline but I haven't found a solution yet.

Anyone know how can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you converting geom to geography. If geom is in 3857 , simply apply ST_Buffer(geom, 10000) for 10 km buffer

Comment: I'm new to GIS. I thought I had to convert them to geography to get buffer in km. I tried it with 3857 as you mentioned and It worked, thanks!